Check for text in cell from separate look-up list and return text from same row but different column in the look-up list
I am hoping for a final bit of help on by bird research study.  I want to search for specific diagnoses (text thread) in a patient's list of diagnoses and then return the body system associated with that diagnosis.
In the example below, Columns A, B, and C are the look-up list.  Column D is the patient number. Column E is the search-in list.  Columns F and G are the desired output lists.
In this example, the first patient (D2,E2) was diagnosed with FIBROSIS, MYOCARDIAL and SHOCK, PULMONARY.  From the All Diagnoses List we can find these two diagnoses and see that FIBROSIS, MYOCARDIAL (A3) affects the cardiovascular system (CARDIO) (B3=Y).  Therefore, the desired output is that the cardiovascular system for the first patient is affected, Y (F2=Y).  The first patient (D2,E2) also has SHOCK, PULMONARY.  SHOCK, PULMONARY (A2) does not affect the CARDIO system (B2=blank) but does affect the respiratory system (RESP) (C2=Y).  So the output for the respiratory system for the first patient is also affected, Y (G2=Y).
For the second patient (D3,E3), the desired output is G3=Y (RESP affected) but F3=blank (CARDIO unaffected). For the third patient (D4, E4), neither the CARDIO or RESP systems are affected, so the desired output is that F4=blank and G4=blank



ALL DIAGNOSES LIST
CARDIO
RESP
PT#
PATIENT'S DIAGNOSIS(ES)
CARDIO
RESP




SHOCK, PULMONARY

Y
1
FIBROSIS, MYOCARDIAL; SHOCK, PULMONARY
Y
Y


FIBROSIS, MYOCARDIAL
Y

2
THROMBOSIS, PULMONARY

Y


THROMBOSIS, PULMONARY

Y
3
EDEMA, CEREBRAL





I hope I've explained my dilemma adequately and I appreciate any and all help!
Lauren.
I have tried some simple SEARCH and XLOOKUP and (IFERROR(INDEX formulas but I can't seem to find a way to return the text from a different column in the look-up list.

Yes!  In a way, they are!  Columns A through Column C are the look-up list, and Columns D through Column G are the patient lists, but yes, in my spreadsheet they are on two different sheets.

But I have not yet made them into two separate tables.  If I need to, I will, but I would prefer not to

You could try using the following formula which uses TEXTSPLIT() as the Lookup_Value component within the XLOOKUP() function:


• Formula used in cell F2
=N(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT($E2,"; "),$A:$A,B:B,"")="Y"))


NOTE: The above formula needs to fill down and fill right, as well instead of adding another function you can use a custom format as well, as [=1]"Y";; where 1 means TRUE while FALSE which means 0 here will be hidden.

Adding another function like IF() to show Y although the custom formatting does that which is actually Facade :


=IF(N(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT($E2,"; "),$A:$A,B:B,"")="Y")),"Y","")


Here is how one can do the custom formatting if avoiding the use one extra function like here IF():


Steps Are:

Select the range of cells or columns (where in to apply the custom formatting)
Hit CTRL+1
Format Cells Window opens up --> From Number Tab --> Select the Category as Custom --> Under Type write the following:


[=1]"Y";;



Oh I hate you... that is so freaking cool. Nicely done.

This sounds cool!  But this is not working for me, with this exact example spreadsheet.  For output I only get a "1" for F2

Wait...this is going somewhere when I copy and paste into different cells... just getting 1s and 0s but will try and change to Ys and blanks.....

@LaurenP can you explain what do you mean by not working for me please refers the notes below the screenshots. It clearly states that in TRUE means 1 while FALSE means 0, so when you select the output range and press CTRL + 1 and click the Number Tab --> Select the Category as Custom if you enter [=1]"Y";; it will show what you need, it avoids the use of another function only.

Don't know how to change 1s and 0s to Ys and blanks....

@LaurenP select the output range here in example as Column F and G. Press CTRL 1 --> It opens Format Cells Dialogue window --> Click on Number Tab --> Under Category select Custom --> Remove anything what you see below the Type and paste [=1]"Y";; now hit ok

This could be a fantastic solution, it's so close!  Can you please help me with changing 1s and 0s to Ys and blanks?

@LaurenP see I have updated refer in answers!

Not working for the main patient database, however.....

Should be working, can you show me a screenshot?

Wait, it's working!!!

I think this may just be it!!!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So, it working for me for Ys but not for blanks in my main database.  At least it's a step forward!!!

Blanks ? It will returns Ys and Blanks

Thank you, I can tell that I am testing your patience. As a novice, I am only trying to navigate this site.  I am grateful for your help, your solution has come to the closest that will work for me.  Please forgive me.  I got a pop up suggesting that I move to a chat since there was so much discussion here.  I am sorry, I won't bother you ant more.

@LaurenP no I'm not bothered but you ask me to join char and then don't respond I was waiting there for your reply butyou don't reply at all.

Thank you, I had never done chat before.  I did not realize that by placing a message in chat that it would summon you.  I guess I should have read the instructions about chat first.  Thank you for your patience as I learn to navigate this site.  I still would love your help if you are interested.  Thanks again.

@LaurenP, you should click accept on this answer as it addresses the problem you posted. The fact that it wasn't a realistic example from your database should not be grounds to withhold awarding a correct answer.

I am not withholding on accepting an answer.  I was going to ask you for a little more help to make this work in my database, but I think I should just accept your answer since it did work for this example.  Hopefully I'll find a solution that works for my database.  Thank you for your time, your answer was brilliant for the example, I wish you the best.

@Mayukh Bhattacharya - I have been spending time on my original database, and it seems like it may be partially working!  I am encouraged!  The only problem is if the search-in cell is empty (E2 in this example), then I get a #VALUE! error.  That is my only problem at this point!  Can you please help me with this one last thing?  I would be so appreciative, and thanks for your patience and kindness with me!

@LaurenP wrap within IFERROR() or keep a control on that by using an IF() --> =IF($E2="","",IF(N(OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT($E2,"; "),$A:$A,B:B,"")="Y")),"Y",""))

updated Answer
My inlaws showed up unannounced, inspiring me to race back to my computer and improve my answer. Paste the improved makearray formula in F2

Shorter than previous answer
Improved calculation speed doing almost calculations the least number of times, while still being flexible for more columns.
Allows for your y approach
Should expand dynamically if you add more columns in the parameter (i.e. inserted a column between B and C)

=LET(PatientCol,$E:$E,sicklist,$A:$A,zSearchCols,$B:$C,
iRows,COUNTA(sicklist),zSearchClean,TAKE(zSearchCols,iRows),zSickCol,
TAKE(sicklist,iRows),
keyCol,DROP(TAKE(PatientCol,COUNTA(PatientCol)),1),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(keyCol),COLUMNS(zSearchCols),LAMBDA(r,c,
IF(LET(patientVal,INDEX(PatientCol,r+1,1),iCol,TEXTSPLIT(patientVal,";"),
purelist,FILTER(zSickCol,INDEX(zSearchClean,,c)="Y"),colList,
BYCOL(iCol,LAMBDA(iVal,ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(iVal),purelist,0)))),
REDUCE(FALSE,colList,LAMBDA(oldVal,newVal,IF(oldVal,TRUE,newVal)))),"Y",""))))

original answer
Throw this cell F2  and you should have true false values to display in all rows and both columns. If you really want to display Y and blank you can use an if-statement or something. You could probably shorten this, but it's all i got the heart for today. good luck.
=HSTACK(LET(PatientCol,$E:$E,sickList,$A:$A,testCol,B:B,BYROW(DROP(TAKE(PatientCol,
COUNTA(PatientCol)),1),LAMBDA(patientVal,LET(pureList,FILTER(sickList,testCol="Y"),
iCol,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(patientVal,";")),colList,BYCOL(iCol,LAMBDA(iVal,
ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(iVal),pureList,0)))),finalResult,REDUCE(FALSE,colList,LAMBDA(oldVal,newVal,IF(oldVal,TRUE,newVal))),finalResult)))),LET(PatientCol,$E:$E,sickList,$A:$A,testCol,C:C,BYROW(DROP(TAKE(PatientCol,
COUNTA(PatientCol)),1),LAMBDA(patientVal,LET(pureList,FILTER(sickList,testCol="Y"),
iCol,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(patientVal,";")),colList,BYCOL(iCol,LAMBDA(iVal,
ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(iVal),pureList,0)))),finalResult,REDUCE(FALSE,colList,LAMBDA(oldVal,newVal,IF(oldVal,TRUE,newVal))),finalResult)))))




This looks very complicated, with PatientCol, PatielVat, sickList, OldVal, NewVal, etc etc. I don't understand all of these terms.  I am grateful for your help, but I am not sure how to apply to my spreadsheet....

You just paste it into the cell. Those are variables. You can call them what you want.

Apologies for the complicated answer. This is StackOverflow. Maybe you might find something more your speed on Quora?

That worked for this example table quite well!  Wow!  Now let me see if I can apply to my research data table.  Thanks!  Will let you know!  Incredible how you came up with this so quickly!

Not playing well in my original database. Getting ## for output values.  Working on it.... but looks so very hopeful....

In the header row of the "PATIENT'S DIAGNOSIS(ES)" table, enter the following formula (it is entered in G1 in the example):
=LET(
    pt_diags, F2:F4,
    so_all_diags, SORT(TRIM(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$4)),
    diag_col, 1, cardio_col, 2, resp_col, 3,
    pt_diag_cat_YN, LAMBDA(acc, entry,
        LET(
            diags, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(entry, , ";")),
            matched_diag_rows, IFERROR(
                CHOOSEROWS(so_all_diags, XMATCH(diags, INDEX(so_all_diags, , diag_col), , 2)),
                HSTACK("", "", "")
            ),
            matched_counts, HSTACK(
                SUM(--INDEX(matched_diag_rows = "Y", , cardio_col)),
                SUM(--INDEX(matched_diag_rows = "Y", , resp_col))
            ),
            VSTACK(acc, IF(matched_counts, "Y", "N"))
        )
    ),
    REDUCE({"CARDIO", "RESP"}, pt_diags, pt_diag_cat_YN)
)

Steps:

Define input ranges: pt_diags, F2:F4, and so_all_diags, SORT(TRIM(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$4)),

Sorting the entries improves lookup speed


column numbers in "ALL DIAGNOSES LIST": diag_col, 1, cardio_col, 2, resp_col, 3,
function to get "Y/N" for each category for each entry in "PATIENT'S DIAGNOSIS(ES)":

 pt_diag_cat_YN, LAMBDA(acc, entry,
split individual diagnosis by splitting:  diags, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(entry, , ";")),
get the matching rows in "ALL DIAGNOSES LIST", (with binary search option 2 for XMATCH):
CHOOSEROWS(so_all_diags, XMATCH(diags, INDEX(so_all_diags, , diag_col), , 2))
in matched rows, get the counts for "Y" for catergory columns:
SUM(--INDEX(matched_diag_rows = "Y", , cardio_col)),
SUM(--INDEX(matched_diag_rows = "Y", , resp_col))
stack the results for row:  VSTACK(acc, IF(matched_counts, "Y", "N"))


apply this function to each row in "PATIENT'S DIAGNOSIS(ES)":
 REDUCE({"CARDIO", "RESP"}, pt_diags, pt_diag_cat_YN)



Thank you.  I can easily make a table for my AllDiagList, will only be a simple list of perhaps up to 2000 total rows, but I am concerned about making a table for my PtDiag list since it has 6600 cases and lots of complicated formulas in it already that nkalvi helped me create....

Okay, I made tables, that is a start, but still too complicated.  Can't recognize pt_diags, PATIENT''S DIAGNOSIS(ES), Diag...

Do I need to make tables out of the lists?  I'd really prefer to not create tables from them....  Good to hear from you again!  Almost done with data analysis!

@LaurenP, you have several good answers. Just adding mine for fun :) Good luck in completing your project!

you'll need to use a combination of functions, for the CARDIO column (Column F):
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$4,E2)))>0,XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$4,E2)),B$2:B$4,""),"")

For the RESP column (Column G):
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$4,E2)))>0,XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$4,E2)),C$2:C$4,""),"")

Enter the first formula in F2, second in G2 and copy it down for all patients.

I am so sorry, but this didn't work.  I understand the logic.  I have the two lists on two different sheets but I don't think that is the problem.  I had a "0" as the output for both CARDIO and RESP.  So sorry!


Formula in F2:
=LEFT(DROP(REDUCE(0,E2:E4,LAMBDA(t,p,VSTACK(t,REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(p,"; "),LAMBDA(x,y,x&XLOOKUP(y,A2:A4,B2:C4,{"",""})))))),1))

Note: LEFT() is important here since I assumed that a single diagnoses can lead to both CARDIO and RESP, and if you have multiple diagnoses that would lead to a Y in either category you'd end up with stuff like 'YY' if you don't use it.
Btw, the inner REDUCE() is there to concat all the CARDIO and RESP from each diagnosis and the outer one is there to VSTACK() the output per patient.
